# HTML on-event behaviour after JavaScript exception

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events

I'm working on an old-school site adding validation to a form (`<form onsubmit="return validate_me();">`). However, while I was testing it, a JavaScript exception was thrown, the event continued and changed my test data. If this had happened on a production site, a lot of data could have potentially been accidentally erased.

Is it correct behaviour for an event to continue unimpeded when an exception is thrown? I would have assumed that an explicit `true` would need to be returned for the event to continue. Is there a way to NOT continue an event after an unhandled exception?

Comment: I will assume you are talking about event propagation, because your handler's execution should stop after an unhandled exception.So if we rewrite the question to *Is there a way to [stop the propagation of] an event after an unhandled exception*, then the answer is no. But, you can stop the propagation of an event after an **handled** exception (all depending of the kind of event though): `catch(err){ evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation();}`

Comment: @Kaiido this will only work if he passes the `event` object to his handler. He would have to define `<form onsubmit="return validate_me(event);">` and then define his handler as `function validate_me(evt)`, otherwise, you're going to get a undefined reference error when you try to access `evt`

Comment: @MicahHunsberger yes obviously, I don't see your point. But using event attribute is not the correct way to assign event handlers anyway, and since it seems he does have multiple handlers, I guess he didn't set all his events through the event attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The form will submit unless an explicit `false` is returned from the `validate_me()` function.

Wrap your whole `validate_me` function in a `try` `catch` block and return false if any JavaScript errors occur in the process like this

```
function validate_me(){
    try{
        //do some stuff
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}
```